# React Router - Nested Routes Not Rendering

Tags: reactjs, web, react-router

I'm currently developing with ReactJS and I am trying to get my head around React Router and it was going well up until now, because for some reason my nested route will not render.

Basically when I navigate to '/home', I want the NavBar to render and the welcome message to be rendered underneath but for some reason only the NavBar is rendered, it forgets about rendering the welcome message. Where I am going wrong?

See code sample below.

Thanks.

```
ReactDOM.render((
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Login}/>
    <Route path="/signup" component={Signup}/>
    <Route path="/companyregistration" component={CompanyRegistration}/>
    <Route path="/adduserdetails" component={AddUserDetails}/>
    <Route component={NavBar}>
      <Route path="/home" component={Welcome} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById("app"))
```

EDIT - NavBar:

```
export default React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <AppBar
            showMenuIconButton={false}
            title={<img src={"img/logo-nav.png"}/>}
            iconElementRight={
                <RaisedButton 
                  onClick={signOut} 
                  label="Sign Out" 
                  primary={true} 
                  style={styles.button}         
                  icon={ 
                      <FontAwesome 
                        className='super-crazy-colors' 
                        name='sign-out' 
                        style={{ color: '#B71C1C' }}
                      />
                    }
                />
            }
          /> 
          {console.log(this.props.children)}
          <div>{this.props.children}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Still nothing is rendering, but console.log(this.props.children) is returning 'undefined' to the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outer route handler (in this case `NavBar`) is a parent component and the inner route handler (`Welcome`) is a child component.

In order for `Welcome` to render, you must output `this.props.children` in the `render` method of `NavBar`.

However, the name `NavBar` sounds more appropriate as a *reusable* component than as a *parent* component. An alternative approach would be to render `NavBar` within `Welcome`.

Comment: I've added my code for navbar.js, could you show me how I would implement this.props.children. Very new to this, sorry. I know I have to create a constructor, but I'm not sure how I would go about this.

Comment: In NavBar render method just have this somewhere: `<div> {this.props.children} </div>`

Comment: @Jayce444 I've done that now and the nested route is still not rendering. There are no compile errors but {console.log(this.props.children)} is returning 'undefined' to the console. Not sure where I went wrong.